# Adding a value into dictionary from a list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I hope all of you are in the best shape. Here I would like to ask how can I add values from List into a Dictionary. As you can see below is the code.

I left the value section as an empty value, in which the elements from the list named after the message should be appended into their respective keys which are the languages.

Thanks for the help lads!

```py
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda']
dict = {'bahasa': '' , 'inggeris' : ''  , 'jerman' : '' , 'turki' : '', 'korea' : ''}


for x in message:
    for y in dict.values():
            dict[x] = y

print(dict)
```

expected result:

```py
dict = {'bahasa': 'lazat' , 'inggeris' : 'delicious'  , 'jerman' : 'lecker' , 'turki' : 'nefis', 'korea' : 'maa ssit dda'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda'] 
dict = {'bahasa': '' , 'inggeris' : '' , 'jerman' : '' , 'turki' : '', 'korea' : ''}
count = 0
for key, val in dict.items():
     dict[key] = message[count]
     count += 1
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{'bahasa': 'lazat' , 'inggeris' : 'delicious' , 'jerman' : 'lecker' , 'turki' : 'nefis', 'korea' : 'maa ssit dda'}
```

Here is the best solution:

```
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda'] 
dict_lan = {'bahasa': '' , 'inggeris' : '' , 'jerman' : '' , 'turki' : '', 'korea' : ''}

for val_mes, key_dict_lan in zip(message, dict_lan):
     dict_lan[key_dict_lan] = val_mes
print(dict_lan)
```

It is better not to call variables by object type names.

Comment: Using a variable outside a loop is quite unpythonic. I would consider using zip() or a comprehension.

Comment: It is possible, but no additional knowledge is required for beginners.

Comment: It is best not to intentionally encourage bad practice.

Comment: thanks guys. I did try and it works. Yes I am an absolute beginner. thanks for your concern.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the keys, and list:

```
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda'] 

my_dict = {'bahasa': '' , 'inggeris' : '' , 'jerman' : '' , 'turki' : '', 'korea' : ''}
for k, v in zip(my_dict.keys(), message):
  my_dict[k] = v
```

btw, don't use (dict) as a name. it's reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Try dictionary comprehension:

```py
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda']
dic = {'bahasa': '' , 'inggeris' : ''  , 'jerman' : '' , 'turki' : '', 'korea' : ''}

print({key: val for key, val in zip(dic, message)})
```

or just

```
print(dict(zip(dic, message)))
```

output:

```
{'bahasa': 'lazat', 'inggeris': 'delicious', 'jerman': 'lecker', 'turki': 'nefis', 'korea': 'maa ssit dda'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not give a variable name the name `dict` as that is the name of the constructor for the dict type.

In your case, use zip since both iterables are of the same length. It is the perfect use case and doesn't require comprehensions.

```
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda']
my_dict = {'bahasa': '', 'inggeris' : '', 'jerman': '' , 'turki': '', 'korea': ''}

for phrase, language in zip(message, my_dict):
    my_dict[language] = phrase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message = ['lazat', 'delicious', 'lecker', 'nefis', 'maa ssit dda']
a_dict = {'bahasa': '', 'inggeris': '', 'jerman': '', 'turki': '', 'korea': ''}

out = {k: message[i] for i, k in enumerate(a_dict.keys())}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'bahasa': 'lazat', 'inggeris': 'delicious', 'jerman': 'lecker', 'turki': 'nefis', 'korea': 'maa ssit dda'}
```

Comment: is this the lean way to write the code as a programmer ?